# Why doesn't magnetic forces on current carrying wire depends on relative velocity?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, classical-electrodynamics, magnetohydrodynamics

We know that magnetic field arises due to relative velocity of charged particle . Electrons in wire move at very slow drift velocity but relativistic variation of magnetic field doesn't seem to apply on them because if observer also travels with drift velocity , magnetic forces on wire should vanish if its in external magnetic field but it doesn't ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to relativity (hence the effects of Lorentz transformations on the electromagnetic tensor), the magnetic field vanishes, but an "apparent" electric field appears.

Comment: Can you show some mathematics about that?

Comment: http://physicspages.com/2013/03/26/electromagnetic-field-tensor-lorentz-transformations/